# How do you add rows to a datatable through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I want to add rows to the datatable when the page is displayed using a javascript array. I am trying to figure this out, but the row does not get added.

```js
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable().fnAddData([
  '1', '1', '1'
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Host</th>
      <th>Method</th>
      <th>SSL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code works fine, but [only with version 1.9.x (or earlier) of the plugin](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnAddData).

```js
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable().fnAddData([
  '1', '1', '1'
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Host</th>
      <th>Method</th>
      <th>SSL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Following the examples on the [datatables.net web site](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) for the latest version (1.10.x):

```js
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable().row.add([
  '1', '1', '1'
]).draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Host</th>
      <th>Method</th>
      <th>SSL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The code that you suggested, works perfect... But it throwing a warning saying that the datatable cannot be reinitialized. Any solution on that?              It works in JSFiddle, not sure why... I think I am missing some library

Comment: You must have initialized it somewhere else already. Store `$('#dataTables-example').dataTable()` in a variable the first time, and use that instead.

Comment: Perfect! Well the issue was that it was using in another file, but was running in the same session. I renamed this table, and it works perfect now. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: any idea how to add checkbox column in rows.add?

Answer (score 4):

From the [API](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html), this is one of the ways to add rows:

```
var dataTable = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable();
dataTable.row.add(['1','1','1' ]).draw();
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t01va0wd/)

Comment: This works, but it is throwing a warning that cannot reinitialize Datatable. For more information, http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: That may mean that you've already insitialized datatable somewhere else in your code, such as `$(selector).DataTable()`

Comment: It works in your fiddle, but not on my stand alone machine. Not sure why!

Comment: No, I have only the following declaration::::      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">

Comment: Not the HTML, I was referring to your script block. Do you have `$('#dataTables-example').DataTable()` twice on the page after adding from my answer?

Comment: No, I don't it twice... I have it only once.............    var dataTable = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable();

Comment: Well, that's what the error actually means. Anyway, try `var dataTable = $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({destroy: true});` Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/t01va0wd/1/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77023/discussion-between-ashwin-tumma-and-lshetty).

Comment: Well the issue was that it was using in another file, but was running in the same session. I renamed this table, and it works perfect now. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

To address the reinitialization warning challenge when using DataTables, you may want to try the retrieve option.  **[www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes](https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3#retrieve)** explains how it works.  You can read about Retrieve **[here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve)**.

> In acknowledgement that the above code structure isn't always particularly
>   attractive, DataTables as a retrieve [[DT]](https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve) option which can be used to tell
>   DataTables that you are aware that the initialisation options can't be
>   changed after initialisation, and that should that occur, that you
>   just want the DataTable instance to be returned.
>
> This optional parameter can provide a short-cut to the explicit check
>   using $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable() as above when obtaining a
>   DataTables instance:
>
> ```
> table = $('#example').DataTable( {
> retrieve: true,
> paging: false } );
> ```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can generate the row before and then append it to the tbody just using jQuery

```
$("#dataTables-example > tbody").append("<tr><td>row content</td></tr>");
```

Comment: OP is using the DataTables plugin to add/manipulate data programatically.