# Adding row in table that has pagination but it is not adding in end

Tags: datatable

I have a table with pagination that has 29 rows in it. I want to add a new row after the last row in the table. I am using following code to add new row in the table.

```
var table = document.getElementById("MyExistingRandomTaskList");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); // Serial No
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); // Task No
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2); // Task Description
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3); // Assign Date
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4); // Task Timeline
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5); // Assign To
var cell7 = row.insertCell(6); // Complete %
var cell8 = row.insertCell(7); // Status
var cell9 = row.insertCell(8); // Edit Icon

cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("MyExistingRandomTaskList").rows.length;
cell2.innerHTML = "R-1";
cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("rbDescription").value;
cell4.innerHTML = "01-01-2021";
cell5.innerHTML = rStartDate + "-" + rEndDate;
cell6.innerHTML = "Assign To Many";
cell7.innerHTML = "0%";
cell8.innerHTML = "Working On";         
cell9.innerHTML = "Edit";
                    
cell1.align = cell2.align = cell3.align = cell4.align = cell5.align = "left";
cell6.align = cell7.align = cell8.align = cell9.align = "left";

var myTable = $('#MyExistingRandomTaskList').DataTable();
myTable.draw();
```

Comment: Add the row to the DataTable using [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) - do not add the data directly to the DOM (the HTML table). There is no guarantee that the row will be added "in end" (which I assume means "the last row displayed in the table"), since its position will depend on what sorting & filtering may be in effect when the table is re-drawn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding rows to datatable through javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056500/adding-rows-to-datatable-through-javascript)